# Setting up a local development environment on xampp for magento

Tags: magento2, database, development, git, aws

Currently we are using an ec2 as a development server, and using rds as a mysql db, we are using git as version control, but I am looking at using git to download and install a local version of the website for testing purposes. How do I do this specifically from the standpoint of the magento database working on a local environment vs current development environment? I can't find much information on how it's supposed to work.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how to do it specifically from the standpoint of the magento database working on a local environment vs current development environment.  I can't find much information on how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking at using git to download and install a local verision of the website for testing purposes.

...

> how to do it specifically from the standpoint of the magento database working on a local environment vs current development environment

Git is for source control, you cannot use it to synchronize databases, if that was your intention.

There are many *specific* ways to get a test system running with a copy of the database, but as long as you are not specific about your requirements, the answer can only be unspecific as well:

1. export the database on remote system (with `mysqldump` or the db management tool of your choice)
2. import the database on local system
3. change `base_url` and `cookie_domain` settings in the `core_config_data` table according to your local domain (Tipp: automate this step with https://github.com/LimeSoda/LimeSoda_EnvironmentConfiguration or https://github.com/AOEpeople/EnvSettingsTool)

Your `app/etc/local.xml` which contains the database credentials should be excluded from Git (add to `.gitignore` file) and generated seperately for each system